# what's an online service that logs your users' exceptions?

Tags: iphone, xcode, reporting-services, exception

A few months ago I came across service where you could make your code report exceptions to their website, and then you can get an overview of all your users' exceptions. Unfortunately I didn't bookmark the page and I can't remember the URL.

Does anyone know of such a service? I doesn't matter if it's the same website I found or not. It'd be good if is supports iOS (iPhone os).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home). Started life as a Rails error tracker, supports iOS now.

Answer (score 1):

iTunesConnect gives you reports for people that submit them through iTunes (users are prompted automatically when they sync).

[Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/) also has the ability to log exceptions, and supports the iOS platform among others.

Answer (score 0):

Flurry supports that. I have a couple of apps that log exceptions and it works pretty well. Their most simple guide to integrating Flurry includes steps for logging exceptions.